# Guessing on the SATs, is it ever better to leave it blank than to guess?

Tags: probability, soft-question, optimization, proof-verification, expectation

On most SAT questions, there are 5 answers of which exactly one is correct and exactly four are wrong. If one answers correctly you get $1$ point. If you answer incorrectly, you receive $-\frac14$ points. If you answer no options, you receive $0$ points. You may not answer multiple questions.

It is said by the SAT test creators that leaving an answer blank is better than blind guessing, and I blindly believed them. I then thought, *are they actually correct!*

You see, the way I see, there is one answer for which you receive $1$ point and 4 answers for which you recieve $-\frac14$ points. Therefore in the long run, you would get $0$ on blind guesses, which is the same as the $0$ you get for not answering. Therefore guessing (blind or otherwise) is at least as good as leaving it blank in the long run no matter how much you know about the question.

Is this reasoning correct? I can't see a flaw in my reasoning, but its my argument against the authority of the SAT people. It seems more likely that my reasoning is a flaw, but I can not find it.

Note: Although this is not strictly necessary, but if my reasoning is correct, it would be good to cite reputable sources to build up a case to convince my school so they could inform students (people outside mathematics listen to authority, not reason.)

Comment: It would be wrong to say that it's at least as good to guess blindly. In the long run it won't make much of a difference which you choose (recommending leaving a blank is known as "loss aversion", and is a fenomenon that has no rationale in a strict risk-vs-payoff view). However, if you can rule out one or two options you should guess, since the odds are suddenly in your favour.

Comment: @Arthur Do you have proof? What is the error in my proof?

Comment: In my opinion it is wrong to say "at least as good" because you might end up worse.

Comment: @Arthur Oh yes. I clarified that in the long run it will be as good or better.

Comment: Well, assuming you always answer a question whether you know it or not, the expected value is $0$. Based on the correct answer being worth a single point and the incorrect answers losing $\large\frac{1}{4}$ there isn't an advantage answer or not answering. As mentioned above, if you can eliminate a single option, it would suddenly be to your advantage to guess. This is all assuming your point system is correct which I believe it isn't. At least, when I was in high school you were penalized more than a quarter of a point.

Comment: @Vincent: I was in high school longer ago than you (at least if the age on your profile is accurate) and I remember teachers explicitly pointing out to us that the expected value would be the same either way -- in contrast to the AMC exams, which genuinely penalized guessing...

Comment: I may very well have it wrong. Or, I'm confusing it with some other standardized test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If points are awarded as you say, then indeed the expected points you can gain from choosing one of the five answers randomly is
$$Ep=1/5*1-4/5*1/4=4/20-4/20=0.$$
However, you are missing the fact that this happens only in expectation, so it is *not* the case that

> guessing (blind or otherwise) is *always* at least as good as leaving it blank.

You can put it another way: in 4 out of 5 cases guessing is worse than leaving it blank. Though fair enough, in 1 out of 5 you are better off.

Another point: people are usually risk averse, that is, would rather have 0 for sure than 0 in expectation, because the latter implies you sometimes get a negative score. But this is a matter of your preferences: if you are generally a gambler, then you might as well guess and gamble that you got the right answer.

Finally, as noted in the comments, as soon as you can reasonably rule out some options or can at least order the answers with respect to likelihood of being correct, then you should guess (but not blindly, i.e., pick the answer you think is most likely).

Comment: I clarified to what I meant by always in the question.

Comment: This is a great explanation of expected value.

Comment: Another note is that it doesn't matter how much information you have about the question. If you even think the one answer looks more rightish, or that it looks like other right answers, you should pick it instead of leaving blank.

Comment: I guess another thing to note is that the variance of guessing one question is small, and if you guess on many questions, the overall variance is still pretty small due to the way probability works (although at that point you probably are not doing great anyways).

Answer (score 0):

Always take the educated guess. You often can exclude one or two silly answers, and with chance 1 out of 3 you beat leaving it blank with a few points.

For example: what is the main chemical element on the moon?

1. Water
2. Cheese
3. Oxygen
4. Iron
5. Silicon

Well, if you know it's not cheese, and even Water is not an element, you can take a random pick out the 3 other options to beat the odds.

Comment: I would ask which moon.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is right. In 4 out of 5 you are getting - 1/4 in 1 out of it is +1. This means mathematically speaking it does in the long term not make a difference  if you guess or leave an answer blank. But that means it is exactly as good,  not at least as good: on single test where you don't know any answers it might turn out worse or better.

I could think of some cases where it might following this thoughts be actually wise to guess: When your only chance to pass is luck. But you are usually not going to be in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't guess for two reasons:
1-If you're wrong, you're giving proof that you haven't learned your lessons, rules, theorems...
2-You want to know your real level through SAT. If by guessing, you get some correct answers, then the score you'll have won't reflect your real value and skills.

Comment: But it has been shown here that guessing doesn't improve or lessen you score on average, it just skews what knowledge you appear to know and not know on the test.  Also a wrong answer is not proof that you haven't learned your lessons, rules, theorems... it could just be that a person got confused and/or distracted on that particular question, was running low on time, or maybe they knew the correct answer at some point and forgot it under pressure (which means they DID learn it but just couldn't recall it).  Also, a correct answer might not show understanding, it could just be a regurgitation.

Comment: @David:You're probably right. But the more the contender is prepared, the more they'll be able to answer.

Comment: @mathink They should have thought of that when they designed the test.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have bad luck guessing then it would be better in that case to leave it blank.  Since it is a SAT and not a SGT, they should penalize more for a wrong answer such as -1/2 so that if someone doesn't know an answer, they are less inclined to guess.  Then they might get a better assessment of aptitude rather than guessing "skills" (actually luck).  +1 for each correct answer, -1/2 for each wrong answer, and 0 for each blank answer would be my recommendation.